# Correct mapping correct route to action with similar url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have two required paths:

1: localhost:1207/Blog/2014/12/Article-Name

2: localhost:1207/Blog/2014/12

Now I have wrote custom mapping for each route

1:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BlogArticle",
            url: "blog/{year}/{month}/{title}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Blog", 
                action = "Detail", 
                year = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                month = UrlParameter.Optional, 
                title = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

2:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BlogMonthList",
            url: "blog/{year}/{month}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Blog",
                action = "MonthList",
                year = UrlParameter.Optional,
                month = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

the second does not work, I am unsure why.
As part of the answer, could you please explain why?

My solution has to use RouteConfig.cs

Example of my controller:

```
public BlogController : Controller{
    public ActionResult MonthList(int year, int month)
    {
        var model = new MonthArticlesModel()
        {
            Year = year,
            Month = month            
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Detail(int year, int month, string title)
    {
        var model = new DetailModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

}

Comment: Are `year` and `month` really optional in both routes?

Comment: The year month parameters should not be optional

Comment: It that case my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no way to distinguish between the routes because you have made all the parameters optional and both `/Blog/2014/12/Article-Name` and `/Blog/2014/12` match the first route.

I recommend you follow more conventional routes, however you can make this work by specifying the routes as

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "BlogMonthList",
  url: "blog/{year}/{month}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "MonthList" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "BlogArticle",
  url: "blog/{year}/{month}/{title}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Detail" }
);
```

Then `/Blog/2014/12/Article-Name` will skip the first route (which only accepts 2 parameters) and redirect to `Detail(int year, int month, string title)` but `/Blog/2014/12` will match the first route and redirect to `MonthList(int year, int month)`

Comment: I have updated my implementation but the month list action is not being resolved

Comment: Works for me. Are these the first 2 routes and are they in the order I have shown?

Comment: Are your methods `public ActionResult MonthList(int year, int month)` and `public ActionResult Detail(int year, int month, string title)`?

Comment: Must be some other issue at play. I copied your controller and the routes from my answer into my project and it works fine. `/Blog/2014/12/Article-Name` hits `Detail` and `/Blog/2014/12` hits `MonthList`

Comment: turns out i had default route above my specific